# "Text Buffer too large" error in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my Unity Project I am getting an error like **"Optimized GUI Block text buffer too large. Not appending further text.
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)"**
I tried converting unnecessary public objects and strings to private but i am still getting the same error.
I still have more than 100 public buttons(I should have), and a string array with the size 205*9 and another one with size 49*13. Is there anyway that I can get rid of this error? Maybe splitting the arrays to smaller ones? And does this error somehow cause any malfunctioning in the game?

```
private string[,] countriesEN=new string[201,9]{
    {"ENGLAND","6","1", "Which one is the capital city of England?","Londra", "İstanbul","İzmir","Elazığ","Londra" },
    {"ENGLAND","6","2", "Which currency does England use?","Pound", "Euro","Dolar","Dinar","Pound" },
    {"ENGLAND","6","3", "Which of the following rivers exist in England?","Thames", "Tuna","Fırat","Nil","Thames" },
    {"ENGLAND","6","4","Who is the first woman Prime Minister of United Kingdom?","Margaret Thatcher","Tansu Ciller","Golda Meir","Agatha Christie","Margaret Thatcher"}
.
.
.
.
};
```

I leave here a part of my big 2 dimensional string array. Since it's too long i just displayed 4 one dimensional arrays.

Comment: Please post the code that shows the variable declaration parts. Just show what they look look because this is part of this issue. While at it, I want to let you know that you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer if the answer solved your issue. I said this because of your other questions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I posted a part of my string for you guys to check out! @Programmer

Comment: The problem is not the array I guess. Unity has a certain limit on how much text may be contained by a text in the UI. How exactly do you use that array? / What is the displayed text in your UI? I got that kind of error when I made a quick and dirty debug log within a Text component just adding more and more lines so the buffer was filled after a while